# How query xml element using linq whether or not the element is existed C#

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am trying to loop through several XML files from my local machine with the same format but some files have the missing element which is the images. when the loop reaches a file with the missing element the program crashes on select new.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
    <id>1663</vid>

    <title>My Title</title>

    <body>
    <und keys="1">
        <n0>
            <value>123 Street</value>
            <summary></summary>
            <format type="NULL"></format>
            <safe_value>123 Street</safe_value>
            <safe_summary></safe_summary>
        </n0>
    </und>
    </body>
   <field keys="1"></field>
   <image>
       <und keys="1">
            <i0>     
                <uri>https://uei.jpg</uri>     
            </i0>
            <i1>
                <uri>https://myurl.jpg</uri>     
            </i1>
        </und>
    </image>
</node>
```

Linq C# (WPF) APP:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(file);
var nodes = from b in document.Descendants("node")
            let imgs = b.Element("image")
            select new
            {
                ID = (string)b.Element("id").Value,
                Title = (string)b.Element("title").Value,
                StreetName = (string)b.Element("body").Element("und").Element("n0").Element("value").Value,
                Images = imgs.Descendants("und").ToList()
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it crashed because of the hard casts?

Try to use save casting and null-conditional operator (?.) this will prevent `NullreferenceExceptions`:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(file);
var nodes = from b in document.Descendants("node")
            let imgs = b.Element("image")
            select new
            {
                ID = b.Element("id")?.Value as string,
                Title = b.Element("title")?.Value as string,
                StreetName = b.Element("body")?.Element("und")?.Element("n0")?.Element("value")?.Value as string,
                Images = imgs?.Descendants("und")?.ToList()
            };
```